# Importing json file into firebase with firebase ID´s

Tags: python, firebase

I generated a dump from one of my tables and every entity looks like this:

```
  {
    "name": "¡Felicidades! Menos cel=más Yumi.",
    "promotion": "Tu paciencia será recompensada con un 2x1 en un cono de yogurt de tu elección.",
    "establishment_id": 1,
    "quantity": 10,
    "validity_date": "2017-09-22",
    "terms": "aplica restricciones",
    "code": "2x1yum",
    "points": 500,
    "active": 0,
    "image": "../uploads/20170511/img-59149a2de8d3b",
    "image_file_name": "2X1.jpg",
    "game_level_id": 0
  },
```

When i use the import option on firebase my database gives the child nodes a numerical ID (1, 2 , 3 etc..) and i want the child nodes to have the custom firebase ID's it gives when you push a new node to the db, i.e.`( HW0vcmYU4MW0zpZX9KlEoVCq1Up2)`

Im trying to write a python script to my table and give every object in the json its unique frebase ID using the admin SDK but i'm stuck trying to iterate through the json.

Should i use an csv instead?
Here is my python function, if i could get some assistance iterating through it i'd appreciate it:

```
import firebase_admin
import csv
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate('./dev.json')

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://url.com/'
})


ref = db.reference('mobile_user/')
// or csv
f = open('coupons.json') 

data = []
for line in f:
    //iteration here
    ref.push(data)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Are you using the `json` library? It makes dealing with json a lot easier, though it can be a bit tricky to learn.

Comment: @mindfolded, no I was unaware that there was one, i'm gonna heck it out